# Does an Anti $\eta^0$ meson exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mesons

An $\eta^0$ meson has a very short lifetime that it hardly ever exists independently. My question is ’With such a short lifetime, is it possible to observe the existence of an Anti $\eta^0$ meson? ( if it ever exists)’

Answer (score 4):

The antiparticle of eta meson is the eta meson itself.

$$ \eta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(u\bar{u} + d\bar{d} -2s\bar{s})$$

As you can see, since the eta is composed of the terms $q\bar{q}$, therefore taking the charge conjugate of $\eta$ will take it back to $\eta$.

Comment: Where can I learn more on this? Any books...

Comment: @AdithyaGopz you can start with reading DJ Griffiths, An Introduction to elementary particles, which is a really nice book..